# Every time I prepare ios app on Ionic GADApplicationIdentifier key change to test

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I am using the library ADMOB PLUS and when I execute "ionic cordova prepare ios", everytime is changing **GADApplicationIdentifier** key on info-list.txt to test, how to solve it? I am new on iOS and cannot get it such behaviour

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in below image created variable

**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free --save --variable ADMOB_APP_ID="<YOUR_ANDROID_ADMOB_APP_ID_AS_FOUND_IN_ADMOB>"**

so create same variable for **GADApplicationIdentifier**

And Pass into config.xml

[image]

**So when your build create for iOS, Same identifier take your variable value.**

Hope it's helpful to you.

Thank you

Comment: Excuse me, but forgot to say I am using admob plus, does it change? I already had on Android working